# MYSQL Start unit not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, unix

Im using AWS Linux 2 AMI
Currently I have `AWS EC2`

Recently the mysql doesn't work anymore but it worked before.

when I tried to do this

`sudo service mysql start`

or

`sudo service mysqld start`

It says `service mysql` unit not found

I tried also to `sudo service httpd start` and start the `mysql` but still doesn't work

I tried also to check the disk usage of my ec2

using this commnad : `df`

This gives me an output like this

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         2000788       0   2000788   0% /dev
tmpfs            2018800       0   2018800   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2018800     480   2018320   1% /run
tmpfs            2018800       0   2018800   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1       8376300 5880760   2495540  71% /
tmpfs             403764       0    403764   0% /run/user/1000
```

Where here /dev/xvdal has `71%` of used storage

Is this even related why `mysql` doesn't want to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran an instance with the descriptions, what I found is that a version of mysql-server is not available in the official repositories, probably you installed mariadb-server, what I want you to do is to execute this command:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep mariadb
```

If you have some match you of course have mariadb instead of mysql installed on your instance so you have to use the next command to start the service:

```
systemctl start mariadb.service
```

If you want the service to start when the instance boot you can type the following command:

```
systemctl enable mariadb.service
```